# código enbebido jQuery a archivo js

Tags: javascript, jquery

muy buenas tardes a todos.
Estoy tratando de agregar audio a ciertos botones en HTML. No se javascript, así que he buscado en internet y encontré esta página:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/

he aplicado algunos cambios para hacer coincidir con mi código como muestro a continuación:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul id="nav-principal" class="navegacion">
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            <audio id="sonido" class="sound" controls="" preload="auto">
                <source src="assets/audio/tic.mp3">
                Su navegador no ha sido invitado al baile.
            </audio>
        </li>
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu" href="pages/info.html">información</a>
        </li>
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu" href="pages/formulario.html">contactanos</a>
        </li>

        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu" href="pages/login.html">login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $("#nav-principal a")
            .each(function (i) {
                if (i !== 0) {
                    $("#sonido")
                        .clone()
                        .attr("id", "sonido" + i)
                        .appendTo($(this).parent());
                }
                $(this).data("beeper", i);
            })
            .mouseenter(function () {
                $("#sonido" + $(this).data("beeper"))[0].play();
            });
        $("#sonido").attr("id", "sonido0");
    </script>
</nav>
```

Funciona perfectamente. Pero ahora me gustaría pasarlo a un archivo `boton.js` para evitar colocar código enbebido dentro del HTML.

En el `<head>` tengo ya colocado el archivo `boton.js`:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/boton.js"></script>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar para comprender mejor como funciona, aprender algo nuevo y así de paso tener un código más limpio.

Lo que yo hice fue copiar el código tal como está dentro del archivo `boton.js` como muestro a continuación :

```
$("#nav-principal a")
    .each(function(i) {
        if (i !== 0) {
            $("#sonido")
                .clone()
                .attr("id", "sonido" + i)
                .appendTo($(this).parent());
        }
        $(this).data("beeper", i);
    })
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $("#sonido" + $(this).data("beeper"))[0].play();
    });
$("#sonido").attr("id", "sonido0");
```

Creí que bastaria solo copiarlo. Pero me doy cuenta que no funciona.

Por otro lado me habría gustado poder asociarlo a una clase `.btn-sonido`. Así lo podría asociar a cualquier boton que tenga esa clase.

Muchas gracias de antemano a quien pueda brindarme una ayuda.

**=========================  EDIT  ==============================**

Estos son los avances que he realizado:

En el archivo `boton.js` he ingresado:

```
// selecciono el elemento de anclaje
let musica = document.querySelector('.musica');

// matriz de retorno
let audioArray = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
console.log(audioArray);

// agregar detectores de eventos
musica.addEventListener('mouseover',() => {
    audioArray[0].play()
});
```

Mientras que en el HTML tengo:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul id="nav-principal" class="navegacion">
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu musica" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            <audio class="enter" src="assets/audio/tic.mp3"></audio>
        </li>
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu musica" href="pages/info.html">información</a>
            <audio class="enter" src="assets/audio/tic.mp3"></audio>
        </li>
        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu musica" href="pages/formulario.html">contactanos</a>
            <audio class="enter" src="assets/audio/tic.mp3"></audio>
        </li>

        <li class="inline">
            <a class="btn btn-menu musica" href="pages/login.html">login</a>
            <audio class="enter" src="assets/audio/tic.mp3"></audio>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Pero al pasar el mouse sobre ellos ...funciona solo el primero!

***Alguna idea?***

Distinguidos saludos

lucho

Comment: Tienes que iterar las matriz de los audios, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excelente día/tarde/noche a todos. quise publicar la respuesta y comentarles como he logrado resolver mi problema.

Para esta nueva prueba he creado un código diferente.

Lo he subido a codepen.io. Lo pueden ver aqui:
https://codepen.io/lucho_/pen/xxWVaGL

Código HTML:

```html
<audio id="tagAudio" class="sonido" src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.mp3">
  Su navegador no ha sido invitado al baile.
</audio>

<p class="text">El código Javascript asocia el audio con id="tagAudio" a todos los botones que tengan clase: "musica" en cualquier parte del documento</p>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menuUno">

    <ul id="nav-principal" class="navegacion">
      <li class="inline">
        <p>menuUno</p>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn  musica" href="#">Texto 12</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn" href="#">NO SUENA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn musica" href="#">Texto 10</a>
      </li>

      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn musica" href="#">Texto 9</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="menuDos">
    <ul id="nav-principal" class="navegacion">
      <li class="inline">
        <p>menuDos</p>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn-menu" href="#">NO SUENA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn-menu musica" href="#">Texto 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn-menu musica" href="#">Texto 3</a>
      </li>

      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn-menu musica" href="#">Texto 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="menuTres">
    <ul id="nav-principal" class="navegacion">
      <li class="inline">
        <p>menuTres</p>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn btn-secundario musica" href="#">Texto 5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn btn-secundario musica" href="#">Texto 6</a>
      </li>
      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn btn-secundario musica" href="#">Texto 7</a>
      </li>

      <li class="inline">
        <a class="btn btn-secundario" href="#">NO SUENA</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Código JavaScript:

```js
let elmMusica = document.getElementsByClassName('musica');
let musica = document.getElementById('tagAudio'); 

for(let i = 0; i < elmMusica.length; i++) { 
  let item = elmMusica[i]
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => { 
    musica.play();
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    musica.currentTime = 0
  });
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos quienes colaboraron. Espero que esta solución pueda servir a alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

Algo así debe de ser el código en boton.js

```
// selecciono el elemento de anclaje
let musica = document.querySelectorAll('.musica');

// matriz de retorno
let audioArray = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
console.log(audioArray);

// agregar detectores de eventos
musica.forEach(function (boton) {
    boton.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        audioArray[0].play()
    });
});
```

La diferencia es que tú utilizaste `querySelector` en lugar de `querySelectorAll`.

`querySelector` sólo regresa el primer elemento que encuentre, en cambio,`querySelectorAll` te va a regresar un array.

Imagino que la confusión es porque en jQuery se maneja así pero en Javascript vanilla debes de hacer un loop sobre la selección regresada de `querySelectorAll` como podrás ver en la línea

```
musica.forEach(function (boton) {
```

Comment: Su respuesta es acertada, pero el lo preguntaba con **jQuery**.

Comment: @Marcos-MD en el momento de responder en ningún lugar de su pregunta decía que necesitaba hacerlo con jQuery. Es más, en las primeras versiones de la pregunta no hubo un sólo ejemplo con jQuery, esa parte el usuario la editó posteriormente.

Comment: En realidad yo lo quería en JavaScript. Lo he especificado en el primer anuncio. @Marcos-MD . Muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Creo que su respuesta fue la más acertada @Wisquimas . Aunque si debo ser sincero, no la he probado aún. Muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITADO:**


Tengo una solución, ya la probé:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  function playSoundOn(element, event, sound) {
    switch (event) {
      case 'click':
        element.append($(`<audio class="play-click" src="${sound}" />`));
        
        element.click(() => {
          $(".play-click", element).each((i) => {
            $(".play-click", element)[i].play();
          });
        });
        break;
      
      case 'hover':
        element.append($(`<audio class="play-hover" src="${sound}" />`));
        
        element.hover(() => {
          $(".play-hover", element).each((i) => {
            $(".play-hover", element)[i].play();
          });
        }, () => {});
        break;
    }
  };
});
```

Para usar la función `playSoundOn` tienes que espicificar:

1. Un elemento seleccionado por **jQuery**.
2. El evento a utilizar, ya sea `click` o `hover`.
3. La ruta al archivo de sonido.

Algo así:

HTML:

```html
...
<div id="btn-0">
    Botón 0
</div>
<div id="btn-1">
    Botón 1
</div>
...
```

JavaScript:

```js
...
playSoundOn($("#btn-0"), "click", "/assets/a.ogg");
playSoundOn($("#btn-1"), "click", "/assets/b.ogg");
...
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Marcos-MD

Su respuesta no funcionó. He colocado su código dentro de codepen. aquí el enlace:

[https://codepen.io/lucho_/pen/yLKeKrJ](https://codepen.io/lucho_/pen/yLKeKrJ) 


Da un error de tipo: `Illegal invocation` 

Saludos Lucho

Comment: Ya puse una nueva respuesta, está probada